# angular2 displaying computed data in template

Tags: javascript, angular

I am just starting to use Angular2 and engaged the following problem.
Template (Main Component):

```
<span *ngFor="#data of dataset" >
    <data-widget [data]="data"></data-widget>
</span>
```

Template (Widget Component):

```
<div>{{someCompValue}}</div>
```

The value of ***someCompValue*** is need to be created from set of properties inside the ***data*** member variable.

Where should I inject the code to compute the someCompValue?
I tried to do it inside constructor() but that moment the ***data*** is not yet assigned (=null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ngOnInit` ([ref](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)):

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular initializes the data-bound input properties.

So in the component:

```
@Component(...)
export class DataWidget {
    @Input data: Xxxx;

    constructor() { ... }

    ngOnInit() {
        // this.data should be set and ready to use here
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Looking at the answer from Günter Zöchbauer, a **note**: use `ngOnInit` if the data is to be calculated *only once at component initialization*; use `ngOnChanges` (as per Günter's answer) if data is to be calculated at the beginning *and recalculated every time the inputs change*.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'data-widget',
  template`<div>{{someCompValue}}</div>`})
class DataWidget {
  @Input() data;
  ngOnChanges(change)  {
    this.someCompValue = doCalculationBasedOnData();
  }
}
```

See also [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) livecycle callback.